find the order of a corresponding group element and prove that the element is not central

Suppose we're given a single column of a character table for a finite group as $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\
 -1\\
0\\
-1\\
-1\\
(-1+i\sqrt{11})/2\\
(-1-i\sqrt{11})/2\\
0\\
-1\\
0\end{bmatrix}$
.


1.Find the order of the corresponding group element.



Prove that the group element is not in the center of G.


For 1, I'm not sure how to find the order of the corresponding group element using only the values in a single column of the character table. Which theorems from character theory could be useful for finding this? There are clearly 10 distinct conjugacy classes of the group. Obviously the order of the entries in the column doesn't matter.
For 2, we clearly just need to find one element h in G so that $gh\neq hg,$ but I'm not sure how to find such an h. There might be some useful properties about central group elements.

To prove the second part, note that $\mathbf Z(G)=\cap_{\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)}\mathbf Z(\chi)$, where $\mathbf Z(\chi)={g\in G:|\chi(g)|=\chi(1)}$.

The inner product of the column with itself gives you the size of the centraliser of the element. This is $11$. Note the size of the group cannot be $11$, as then there would be $11$ distinct conjugacy classes, not $10$.  Thus we just pick $h$ to be any element other than one of these $11$ and we have that $h$ does not commute with our element.
The element generates a subgroup of its centraliser.  Thus its order must divide $11$.  It is not $1$ as there are non-integer values in the column.  Thus the order is $11$.
The character values for an element of order $n$ must be sums of $n$'th roots of unity.  Thus as a sanity check, it is worth noting that:$$(-1+i\sqrt{11})/2=\zeta+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5+\zeta^9,$$ where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i /11}$.
